# JSON elements/Objects count gives wrong number back - JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file, where I need to count the subscriptions entries.

So for example ID=0 should give me a 2 back, cause 2 entries, ID=1 a 3 and so on.

I thought `Object.keys(users.subscriptions).length;` should do it.

But this gives me a 21 back, so it counts each character, instead of entries.

I thought it might be some Database problems, but I dont know for sure.

I use postgresql and specific for subscriptions, I used `text[]` as type.

[image]

Comment: How is the image related to the question? It doesn't show the value of `users.subscriptions` (it shows the values of `users[0].subscriptions` and `users[1].subscriptions`, though). Also, please don't post images of the data, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1169519

Comment: the entries in subscriptions are not relevant, just an string array. I just want to count the entries. so index1 for example, subscriptions: 0: .. 1: .. 2: .. has 3 elements, so I need the 3 back.

Comment: Please re-read my comment above, and compare it to what you've asked.

Comment: (Keys are keys. Characters are elements of a string.)

Comment: I also removed JSON (text, which has no Object.keys relevance) and typescript (only the usage of JS expression is included) and postgres (because only the result of some interaction is shown without any query); none of those tags are shown to be any more relevant than “computer” or “keyboard”.